# Stylistic set substitution doesn't work in subscript with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, stix

I am using TeX Live 2018 with all packages up-to-date.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=2]{STIX2Math.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \max_g g
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I compile the file with xelatex and I get:
[image]

The subscript g does not change to the variant form. Is this a bug of `unicode-math` or the STIX2Math font?

Comment: With LuaLaTeX it works, it seems that XeLaTeX does not change the letters for `\scriptstyle` and smaller, see `\max_g g \scriptstyle g \scriptscriptstyle g` or better `\displaystyle g \textstyle g \scriptstyle g \scriptscriptstyle g`. (Tested on MikTeX 2.9 all packages updated this morning.)

Comment: Probably one for https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues