# Why do stylistic sets break in script-style in XeLaTeX?

Tags: unicode-math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}%
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[StylisticSet={02}]

\begin{document}
$g^g_{g^g}$
\end{document}
```

when we chose the StylisticSet={02}, the 'g' & 'z' shape of the superscript and subscript has not changed. How to control it?

[image]

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you've encountered on my up-to-date MacTeX2018 distribution under LuaLaTeX. I.e., I get the swashy z and the one-storey g in text, script, and scriptscript mode. Please tell us which document class you employ, which TeX engine you employ, and which version of the Stix Two fonts you employ.

Comment: It works with lualatex but fails with xelatex.

Comment: It probably depends on the order of the feature lookups in the font, if ssty (activated by default for script and scriptscript fonts) precedes ss02 then ss02 will have no effect. Checking the font, this is indeed the case, so I think the issue should be reported in https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/issues.

Comment: It's the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442046/82731 and https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/484 .

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug to me, and I haven’t tried to determine whether it’s in `unicode-math` or in XeTeX.  Here is a temporary workaround:

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[StylisticSet=2,
                            script-features={},
                            sscript-features={}]
```

[image: Sample of workaround]

Setting `StylisticSet=2` inside `script-features` does not currently work.  You might limit the scope of the workaround by loading it with `range=`. as in:

```
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[StylisticSet=2]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[StylisticSet=2,
                            range=it/{latin},
                            script-features={},
                            sscript-features={}]
```

Setting the range to only the individual letters that need it does not work, either.

Since only XeTeX currently needs it, you might wrap it in `\ifXeTeX` from the `iftex` package.  That would give you:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase }
\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[
  Scale = 1.0 ,
  Ligatures = {Common, TeX},
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  Extension = .otf ]
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[StylisticSet=2]

\ifXeTeX
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}[StylisticSet=2,
                            range=it/{latin},
                            script-features={},
                            sscript-features={}]
\fi% XeTeX

\begin{document}
$g^g_{g^g}$ $z^z_{z^z}$ $\alpha^\alpha_{\alpha^\alpha}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea to disable the script features. Try e.g. `$x^{2a+b^2}$` with and without them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree that it’s suboptimal, but that’s the workaround I found. The second workaround at least preserves the script features of `2`, capitals and the Greek letters. Do you have a better one? Other than using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: $f_j$ under first method has changed, they are so close to the ground, this is an unexpected impact.

Comment: @poorich Are you able to use LuaLaTeX for the time being?